# Why doesn't the `map()` return type maintain the same number of values as the input?

Tags: typescript

I have some TypeScript code that goes sort of like this:

```
const foo: [string, ...string[]] = ['narf']
const bar: [string, ...string[]] = foo.map((x) => x)
```

The error I'm getting is: `Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '[string, ...string[]]'. ts(2322)`

Well, yes, but `map()` never changes the number of elements in the list, so why doesn't it return the type `[string, ...string[]]`? And what is the recommended fix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We simply don't have a good way to represent this that catches all the edge cases while being sensible to add to the built-in's typings. While you could use something like this to make it work,

```
interface Array<T> {
    map<V>(predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: Array<T>) => V): { [K in keyof this]: V };
}
```

It's probably going to fail in some cases (I already found one - mapping `never[]` results in `unknown[]`), and while we can patch those individual cases (either with more overloads or conditional types), it's simply not feasible to use or maintain.

This *does* work but I would not recommend augmenting built-ins like this...

```
const foo: [string, ...string[]] = ['narf'];
const bar: [string, ...string[]] = foo.map((x) => x); // okay
```

Instead, I would just use an assertion, so that other TypeScript developers that look at the code don't wonder, "wait, why does this work?"

```
const foo: [string, ...string[]] = ['narf'];
const bar: [string, ...string[]] = foo.map((x) => x) as [string, ...string[]]; // okay
```

You are of course, free to use whichever way you'd like.

Related: [microsoft/TypeScript#29841](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29841)

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJSnAngHgCoB8yA3gLABQyVyAtnAA44BqBAFPVBACbAJyQAuZKwBucADYBXCELwAaZKC4QAHkJCSaAI2gK4GbEPSZchAJTIAvESZmhxZAG0A0opDIA1hCwB7GMjAAC2AAZwBdISZkAF8AbgpoigoEHxAQsGQYHx8hR3SoUABzBQA6MvyixzCwqycAchB9GDqw+PIUtIytfVyKkGLkMpK+wqqay0zskrp6VlYVC2tkBbaO9ORugC9cjW1dQbLdnSgx2qyfaYY5hasiFRLxCH6gs1igA)

---

One more sanity check, this also works when using the augment described above...

```
const baz: [number, ...number[]] = foo.map((x) => x.length);
```

Comment: Thanks! I went with the assertion and added a link to this answer in a comment as explanation.

Comment: My latest solution: 
```export const notEmpty = <T,>(list: T[]) => {
  if (list.length == 0) throw new TypeError('List must not be empty')
  return list as [T, ...T[]]
}
```